# git fetch does not update my local branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

I am new to git (have used other version control systems like Perforce) but what I am trying to do seems very basic to do it wrong.

I have a local workspace and a remote one. I want to bring changes from the remote to local (not force update but merge them with my local workspace).

If I do this :

```
git diff master remote_name/master
```

I can see there are a lot of differences.

So, I am trying to fetch stuff from remote :

Tried both :

```
git fetch remote_server
git fetch remote_server master
```

where remote_server is the name I have given (I see this if I run `git remote -v` )

But my local files do not change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch` only does just that - fetches the commits from the remote server into your local copy of the remote branches (see `git branch -a` for a list).

What you probably want is `git pull`, or to do (on master)

```
git fetch remote_server
git merge remotes/origin/master
```

`git pull` (roughly speaking) just combines those two.